# HTML/Javascript show a random value depending on option clicked

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm not very knowledgeable about Javascript I fully admit, so this may be something very simple that I'm just missing. I'm trying to make a 1 week random prompt generator where the different days of the week have different themes with different associated prompts, so people can choose a theme and get a random prompt for that theme. There are main themes and alternative themes, and also a free day that has all the prompts available as options, so total 13 different arrays. I can find lots of tutorials for a general random item from an array, but this one I based off a random name generator code because I couldn't seem to find many that changed which array depending on what's selected or clicked.

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btns"),
  display = document.getElementById("display"),

  theme1 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt1 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme2 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt2 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme3 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt3 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme4 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt4 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme5 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt5 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme6 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt6 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  free = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'];

document.addEventListener("click", makePrompt);
function makePrompt(event){
  const clickedThing = event.target;
  let chosenList;
  if(clickedThing.classList.contains("btns")){
    if(clickedThing.value == "theme1"){ chosenList = theme1; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "themealt1"){ chosenList = themealt1; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "theme2"){ chosenList = theme2; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "themealt2"){ chosenList = themealt2; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "theme3"){ chosenList = theme3; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "themealt3"){ chosenList = themealt3; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "theme4"){ chosenList = theme4; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "themealt4"){ chosenList = themealt4; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "theme5"){ chosenList = theme5; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "themealt5"){ chosenList = themealt5; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "theme6"){ chosenList = theme6; }
    else if(clickedThing.value == "themealt6"){ chosenList = themealt6; }
    else { chosenList = free; }

    const prompt = randFrom(chosenList);
    display.innerHTML = prompt;
  }
}
        
// Gets a random element from an array
function randFrom(array){
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[index];
}
```

```html
<h1>Choose a Day/Theme</h1>
    "Free day" will choose from any prompts
<div>
<button class="btns" value="theme1">Theme 1: </button>
<button class="btns" value="themealt1">Alt Theme 1:</button>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="btns" value="theme2">Theme 2: </button>
<button class="btns" value="themealt2">Alt Theme 2:</button>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="btns" value="theme3">Theme 3: </button>
<button class="btns" value="themealt3">Alt Theme 3:</button>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="btns" value="theme4">Theme 4: </button>
<button class="btns" value="themealt4">Alt Theme 4:</button>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="btns" value="theme5">Theme 5: </button>
<button class="btns" value="themealt5">Alt Theme 5:</button>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="btns" value="theme6">Theme 6: </button>
<button class="btns" value="themealt6">Alt Theme 6:</button>
    </div>
<div>
<button class="btns" value="free">Free day</button>
    </div>

<h1>Prompt</h1>
<p id="display">
</p>
```

Anyway, it's not working, when I click the buttons nothing appears. If there's a newer/easier way to do this kind of thing I would appreciate any advice.

There are actually A LOT of prompts, so ideally the code would retrieve the prompts from an external list, like a text file or something like that, but for now if it can just load the prompts at all that would be great.

Edit: Thank you very much for your help & corrections, I figured out my issue was actually about where I was putting the script in the HTML doc, because I'm that inept with Javascript. Hope some of the code people provided does help someone in the future though.

Comment: I think it works fine, can you add what is the expected result, if I missed something.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari When for example the "Theme 1:" button is clicked, it should show a random prompt from the theme1 array (atm either "prompt 1" or "prompt 2" but I will add more). Currently for me when I press the buttons nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, run the code snippet in the question you will see the prompt at the bottom with random values from the array

Comment: Interesting. Maybe not a code problem but some problem with my browser or something. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have set up your variables like that makes it quite confusing and I think that is the issue. Once you have set all the variables, add the event listener after that.

But then you have to loop over the buttons and add the listener to each one.

```js
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
     buttons[i].addEventListener("click", makePrompt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `comma` instead of a `semi-colon`.

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btns"),
      display = document.getElementById("display"),
      theme1 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
      themealt1 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
      theme2 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
      themealt2 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
      theme3 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
      themealt3 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
      theme4 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
      themealt4 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
      theme5 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
      themealt5 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
      theme6 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
      themealt6 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
      free = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'], // This should be a semi-colon.
```

That is causing an error. Changing that to a semi-colon makes your code work.

```js
const
  buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btns"),
  display = document.getElementById("display"),

  theme1 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt1 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme2 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt2 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme3 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt3 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme4 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt4 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme5 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt5 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  theme6 = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'],
  themealt6 = ['alt prompt 1', 'alt prompt 2'],
  free = ['prompt 1', 'prompt 2'];

  document.addEventListener("click", makePrompt);

function makePrompt(event) {
  const clickedThing = event.target;
  let chosenList;
  if (clickedThing.classList.contains("btns")) {
    if (clickedThing.value == "theme1") {
      chosenList = theme1;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "themealt1") {
      chosenList = themealt1;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "theme2") {
      chosenList = theme2;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "themealt2") {
      chosenList = themealt2;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "theme3") {
      chosenList = theme3;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "themealt3") {
      chosenList = themealt3;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "theme4") {
      chosenList = theme4;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "themealt4") {
      chosenList = themealt4;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "theme5") {
      chosenList = theme5;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "themealt5") {
      chosenList = themealt5;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "theme6") {
      chosenList = theme6;
    } else if (clickedThing.value == "themealt6") {
      chosenList = themealt6;
    } else {
      chosenList = free;
    }

    const
      prompt = randFrom(chosenList);

    display.innerHTML = prompt;
  }
}

// Gets a random element from an array
function randFrom(array) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[index];
}
```

```html
<h1>Choose a Day/Theme</h1>
"Free day" will choose from any prompts
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="theme1">Theme 1: </button>
  <button class="btns" value="themealt1">Alt Theme 1:</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="theme2">Theme 2: </button>
  <button class="btns" value="themealt2">Alt Theme 2:</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="theme3">Theme 3: </button>
  <button class="btns" value="themealt3">Alt Theme 3:</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="theme4">Theme 4: </button>
  <button class="btns" value="themealt4">Alt Theme 4:</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="theme5">Theme 5: </button>
  <button class="btns" value="themealt5">Alt Theme 5:</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="theme6">Theme 6: </button>
  <button class="btns" value="themealt6">Alt Theme 6:</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btns" value="free">Free day</button>
</div>

<h1>Prompt</h1>
<p id="display">
</p>
```

Comment: Hm, I changed that but still nothing is appearing when I click the buttons, unfortunately. Thank you very much though, I'd missed that one.

Comment: Run the snippet. It's the same code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your sample:

- Buttons are rendered based on the dataset, you can add as much you want.
- as list and altlist seem to be linked, combining them made rendering easier
- the click event is bound in it's own wrapper function, so trying to determine what list to call is no longer needed, you already know at that point.

```js
var display = document.getElementById("display");  
var data = [
  { 
    descr: "Theme 1", 
    list: ['prompt 1.1', 'prompt 1.2'],
    altlist: ['alt prompt 1.1', 'alt prompt 1.2']
  },
  { 
    descr: "Theme 2", 
    list: ['prompt 2.1', 'prompt 2.2'],
    altlist: ['alt prompt 2.1', 'alt prompt 2.2']
  },
  { 
    descr: "Free Day", 
    list: ['free 1', 'free 2']
  }
];

function randFrom(array){
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[index];
}

function renderButton(parent, descr, list){
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.className = 'btns';
  button.innerHTML = descr;
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    display.innerHTML = randFrom(list);
  });
  parent.appendChild(button);
}

function render(){
  var btnList = document.getElementById("btnList");
  for(let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++){
    let item = data[i];
    // add div
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    btnList.appendChild(div);
    // add buttons
    renderButton(div, item.descr, item.list);
    if (item.altlist) renderButton(div, "Alt " + item.descr, item.altlist);    
  }  
}
render();
```

```html
<h1>Choose a Day/Theme</h1>
"Free day" will choose from any prompts

<div id="btnList">
</div>

<h1>Prompt</h1>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured out my problem with the original code. Unfortunately  the buttons for Theme and Alt Theme would ideally have totally different labels based on what the themes actually are (eg Theme 1: Brave, Alt Theme 1: Soft, etc) but this code is much nicer than the one I was using.

Comment: Have fun coding, glad to have given you something that was usefull.